# Select all colums from a table and some from another using left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

How do you select all the columns from one table and just some columns from another table using left JOIN? In MySQL

Comment: You need to give us something: the schema/structure of your tables, for example.

Comment: I figured it out thanks for the thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select all columns from table1 (alias a) and only id and name from table2 (alias b)

```
select a.*, b.id, b.name 
 from table1 a 
 inner join table2 b on b.id = a.id
```

Comment: Thanks for actually taking the time to help me and not bashing my question

Comment: @dames ; everbody here is very helpfull but its up to you how to get help. First of all ask question exect to get help fast.